# Android picture gallery (slideshow), for newbies

Tags: android, gallery, slideshow, image

I'm almost a complete beginner at programming (only did some basic a long time ago).

I want to learn how to make Android apps. My goal is to make a simple app that would be some kind of a picture gallery with a slideshow function.
The app would for example integrate ten pictures, there would be two arrows at the bottom of the screen to switch to the next (or previous) picture.
That's about it for a start.

Would any one be kind enough to list the main steps to follow in order to make this app ? 
So far I'm learning the basics through various tutorials, but I'm kind of struggling...

Thanks in advance !

Comment: What are you struggling with? Can you tell us what you have tried so far and how your plan looks like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Make main activity that contains ImageView and two buttons
2. Make function that loads images into array or list
3. Implement listeners for button clicks

Is that enough or You want me to write more about this ?